# Show that if $A$ and $B$ are commuting matrices, then $e^{A+B} = e^Ae^B$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, power-series

> Let $A$, $B$ $\in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ such that $AB = BA$. Consider $e^{A+B} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(A+B)^k}{k!}$. Since $A,B$ commute, $(A+B)^k = \sum_{j=0}^k {k \choose j} A^j B^{k-j}$ by the binomial formula.
>
> Hence, $$e^{A+B} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sum_{j=0}^k {k \choose j} A^j B^{k-j}}{k!}.$$

I am having a tough time simplifying this to get the form $e^Ae^B$. Any tips?

Comment: Hint. $\frac{1}{k!}\binom{k}{j} = \frac{1}{j!}\frac{1}{(k-j)!}.$. Can you rearrange the sum into a double sum using the idea of the Cauchy product?

Comment: Use the substitution $\tilde{j}:=k-j$ and rewrite the double sum as $\sum_{j,\tilde{j}\geq 0}$.

Answer (score 1):

Try working backwards. Note that
$$
\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac 1{j!} x^j\right)
\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{k!} y^k\right) =
\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^j \frac 1{k!}\frac 1{(j-k)!} x^k y^{j-k}
$$

Comment: Hmm, how did you break that up? In my problem I have it simplified to $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{1}{j!(k-j)!}A^jB^{k-j}$. If I define $i = k-j$, then I get $\sum_{i+j=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{i+j} \frac{1}{j!i!}A^jB^i$, but this sum looks really weird to me, particularly how the outer sum is over the quantity $i+j$. After all, we want both indices $i$ and $j$ to be ran over positive integers, and this won't happen if $i=-j$.